# React Hooks stale state inside function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I have something like this

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    num: 0
  });

  const validateBiggerThan0 = () => {
    return state.num > 0;
  };

  const [validation, setValidation] = useState({
    val: validateBiggerThan0
  });
```

The problem is when I call `validation.validateBiggerThan0`, this function does not have the current `state`.
In this simple example, I could pass the value `sate.num` as a parameter to the `validateBiggerThan0`, but in my real application this is not feasible because I have multiple validations and some can use more than one value from the state. Is there any alternative to this?

A sandbox with the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mountain-2poz7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Quick solution `return state ? state.num > 0 : false`

Comment: @Omer did not understand, where?

Comment: In validateBiggerThan0

Comment: @Omer I think you did not understand my question. The `state` is not `undefined`. The problem is that the `state.num` is not updated inside the `validateBiggerThan0`. The answer from @Mat Sz solves my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to not use `useState` for the function object.

```
const validation = {
  val: validateBiggerThan0
};
```

Or to update the object on every change of your state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValidation({
    val: validateBiggerThan0
  });
}, [ state, setValidation, validateBiggerThan0 ]);
// Don't remove "state" from the dependency array.
```

Don't forget to wrap your validation functions in a `useCallback` hook in case you use the `useEffect` method.

```
const validateBiggerThan0 = useCallback(() => {
  return state.num > 0;
}, [state]);
```

Comment: thanks, not using the `useState` may be the best solution for the simpler components I have and I think it will work.
 Another problem is that in some cases I am expecting that the `const validation` will be an array, and some child components will push validations to that array. When I click submit, all validations have to run. Maybe in this case I need to use the `useEffect`