# Pass state data to ipc function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, electron

**Problem**

The event to send data to renderer is triggered on a file change with `chokidar`. When  the file watcher is triggered and the process sends the event to the renderer.

My problem is that when the `EmitterEvent` is triggered I input the current state of my `useState()` variable but only the initial state is passed to my function.

Edited: my problem is that I can not pass the updated `data` variable to the `updateData(newData)` function which is called from the `emitter` inside the `preload.js`.

---

**Question**

How can I pass the state variable `data` to the call ?

Is there a way that I can change my preload.js in order for the `api.receive` function to return a string in order not to have to pass a function to the `emitter` ? (please check the `updateData(newData)` function for more info)

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

This could also help me to initialize the data for the first render.

---

**preload.js**

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["file", "save"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["file", "save"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        },
        

    }
```

**electron.js**

```
function ReadNodesFileToIpc(path) {
  fs.readFile(path, (error, data) => {
    win.webContents.send("file", data);
  });
}
```

**Code in component that receives data**

```
 function MyForceGraphComponent(){ 
  const [data, setData] = useState({ nodes: [{ id: 0, otherinfo: [] }], links: [] });
  var isDataInittiallized = 0;
  ...
 
  function updateData (newData, data) {
    if (data.nodes.length !== 1){ 
      // do stuff

      setData({ nodes:  data.nodes, links: data.links });
    }else{
      if (!isDataInittiallized){
        setData({ nodes:  newData.nodes, links: newData.links });
        isDataInittiallized = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  ...
  useEffect(() => {  
    ...
    window.api.receive("file", (bytesArray) => {
           var newData = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytesArray));
           updateData(newData); // Check function bellow
              
         });
    ...
  }, []);
}
```

---

**updateData(newData)** (a function inside my components fuction)

`isDataInittiallized` is a variable inside the component that **the change got passed to the `emitter`**

`data` is my variable from the useState() function that **the change did **NOT** got passed to the `emitter`** even though the `setData()` previously changed the `data` successfully. So the length remains 1 and it contains the same elements from when it was firstly initialized .

---

**Other info**

Have tried to play with passing the `data` variable to the receive function without any success.

Most probably when the emitter is getting set the function passed (the one that does `JSON.parse`) is getting passed along and never changed after.

Comment: I am assuming your problem is with `updateData` having access to the old/initial state of `data`, and not the updated state?

Comment: Yes, I want the updated state of the `data`, in order to check for changes between the old and and the new `data`. @goto1 Adding, the problem is that the function is called from preloadd.js. I assumed that the function passed to the ` window.api.receive("file", () =>...)` acts like a variable and therefore always gets the updated `data` variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126199/react-hooks-stale-state-inside-function but also, you should use `useState` for `isDataInittiallized` since that's also a `state` that you want to update and keep track of.

Comment: Yes it is working. I did not thought that even that there is one "global" variable not using `useState()` could cause this "not function change effect". Would you mind posting it as the answer in order to mark a solution and I will later try to research for some internals on why this happens  and post them in the  thread  ? Thank you a lot ! @goto1

Comment: I posted a solution with some improvements, take a look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue is related to stale data inside the `updateData` function, I  suggest to make the following updates:

```js
// Simplified for the sake of brevity

function MyForceGraphComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ nodes: [{ id: 0 }] })

  // isDataInitialized needs to be tracked just as any other state
  const [isDataInitialized, setIsDataInitialized] = useState(false)

  // Wrap `updateData` in `React.useCallback` to prevent stale data
  const updateData = useCallback(
    (nextData) => {
      // skip the update, no need to update the state with existing data
      if (isDataInitialized) return;
    
      setData({ nodes: nextData.nodes })
      setIsDataInitialized(true) // set to `true` to prevent future updates
    }, 
    [isDataInitialized, setIsDataInitialized]
  )

  const handleReceivedData = useCallback(
    (bytesArray) => {
      const nextData = JSON.parse(...)
      updateData(nextData)
    }, 
    [updateData]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    window.api.receive('file', handleReceivedData);
  }, [handleReceivedData])
}
```

Have a look at this example that mimics what you're trying to do:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-brook-x2q73?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: So much cleaner and useful thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

There some error in you code that i found. When you call updateData(newData), data is null, data.nodes will not work. you can modify you code, "if (data
&& data.nodes && data.nodes.length !== 1)"